# OpenGL Camera keeps rotating around the origin

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl

There are no errors in this code but when I run the code, the camera is fine, I can look around and all of that. As soon as I move, it starts rotating around the origin of it's spawn.

Camera code:
http://hatebin.com/iiceqotcpu

Main code mouse_callback

```
def mouse_callback(window, xpos, ypos):
    global first_mouse,lastX, lastY
    if first_mouse:
        lastX = xpos
        lastY = ypos
        first_mouse = False

    xoffset = xpos - lastX
    yoffset = lastY - ypos

    lastX = xpos
    lastY = ypos

    cam.process_mouse_movement(xoffset, yoffset)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The translational part of the view matrix should come **before** the rotational part, since you must apply the rotation to the relative position of the point.

```
# before
return translation * rotation

# after
return rotation * translation
```